# How to get rid of noisy warning "No suitable checks publisher found"

Tags: jenkins

One of the **Jenkins** plugins dragged in the **Checks API** as a dependency and now *EVERY* build has this annoying message at the bottom:

```
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
```

This does not fail any build by itself. It's just annoying noise and I don't want it.

And now each time a build fails for any other reason, my developers tell me

> It seems that we have problems with build on foobar machine with 'No suitable checks publisher found' error again.

which is incorrect, the actual error is just above or below that warning.

This is a waste of time, I never want to see that warning again. How do I get rid of it?

I can't uninstall **Checks API**, it's grayed out. **JUnit** and **Warnings Next Generation** need it as a dependency.

- Jenkins: 2.277.2
- Checks API: 1.7.0

Comment: If anyone is still going to answer this question, go ahead, but after a month we've given up and just accept that the messages are there.

Answer (score 18):

You can disable the check feature by:

```
junit testResults: 'results.xml', skipPublishingChecks: true
```

Check the README.md of JUnit plugin for more details:

```
Test result checks (for GitHub projects)
⚠️ This feature requires:

the installation of an additional plugin: GitHub Checks Plugin
the configuration of GitHub App credentails, see this guide for more details.
If not disabled in the job configuration, this plugin will publish test results to GitHub through GitHub checks API.

In the Details view of each check (example), test results will be displayed.

checks

In order to disable the checks feature, set the property skipPublishingChecks to true:
```

References:

- JUnit README: https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/blob/master/README.md
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/checks-api-plugin/issues/38

Comment: When I enable `skipPublishingChecks`, jenkins will not even publish the test results to itself. With `skipPublishingChecks` off, I get another item on the Jenkins build that display everything with the test results (##/testReport) but I also get that warning. Is there anyway to have Jenkins display the test results without giving this warning?

Comment: This warning appears even in the most simple freestyle jobs. I just created one that does "echo hello" and right after the line "Building remotely on <agent>", the warning `[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.` appears!

Answer (score 0):

With the following action in my `Jenkinsfile`...

```
    post {
        always {
            junit testResults: '**/cpputest_*.xml'
        }
    }
```

I get the

```
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
```

warning as described in the original question.

Adding the "skipPublishingChecks" option as described in [the junit plugin's readme file](https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/blob/master/README.md)...

```
    post {
        always {
            junit skipPublishingChecks: true, testResults: '**/cpputest_*.xml'
        }
    }
```

...results in the warning no longer being shown.
In my case (vanilla Jenkins 2.365), and contrary to a comment by @rveach above, the test result trend is still shown (and updated) on the job's 'Stage view' page.